# R: Abline from lm(y~x, data) does not fit my data

Tags: r, statistics

I have two vectors and I am trying to fit a linear model using `lm(y~x, data)`.
The results I am getting are:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.5712      -0.1092
```

Also when running `summary(lm(y~x, data=data))` I am getting as r squared 0.033. You can see that here:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-3.856 -3.018  1.845  2.541  3.695 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.5712     0.8837   0.646    0.526
x            -0.1092     0.1374  -0.794    0.437

Residual standard error: 3.033 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.03387,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.0198 
F-statistic: 0.631 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.4373
```

When plotting the results, I am using `abline(lm(y~x, data=data))` to illustrate the fitted model along with my data. Here is the plot:

[image]

The correlation (r squared) seems good to me but the fitted line seems that it is not fitting my data. I would expect the line to be more horizontal because now it seems that it represents a correlation higher than 0.033. Any ideas why this is happening?

I am providing the two vectors I am using:

```
x <- c(0.000000, 3.731577, 7.159587, 0.000000, 0.000000, 7.525843, 15.890714, 1.122046, 0.000000, 4.517200, 16.086196, 0.000000, 5.091981, 3.285380, 9.600572, 0.000000, 0.000000, 2.253814, 6.190752, 0.000000)

y0 <- c(208.645, 232.990, -838.295, -649.825, -1926.875, -1290.235, -1320.595, -619.325, 1316.910, 787.470, 323.525, 843.570, 90.400, -2040.355, -2635.250, -1240.815, 1288.130, 915.360, 1035.425, 1289.135)

y <- sign(y0)*log10(abs(y0)) # To log both negative and positive values
```

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions about what the correlation coefficient means. It simply is the fraction of total variance explained by the model. It doesn't say anything about the coefficients of the model. The values on the upper left are clustered a bit more towards the left, which results in the estimated slope

Comment: Look at the model R^2! The model does not explain much.

Comment: Actually before concerning about the R^2, you should concern about the statistically insignificant variables. However, I agree with you about the line. If your entire data is the points are shown, it looks like there is a problem. Are you sure that your data has been read as numeric by R? They may be taken as characters or factors. This sloping curve is not normal wrt those data points.